# What's the difference between a javascript function as a property of window, a function defined with a name

Tags: javascript, function, global-scope

What's the difference between

```
function doStuff(){
    //do lots of fun stuff
}
```

and

```
window.doStuff = function(){
    //do lots of fun stuff
}
```

if any?

Comment: yep, it's a dupe, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first will create a doStuff function property in whatever is the current scope context.  If that is window (or no scope defined), then the result will be the same as the second *in a browser context*.  If the current scope, though, is for example within another function, then only a locally available function will be created and the effect will not be the same as the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

There is no big difference if you declare function in global scope.
Difference appears when scope of code, where you are declaring a function is not global.
For example, inside another function:

```
function doGlobalStuff()
{
    function doStuff(){
    // do lots of fun stuff
    }
}
```

If you execute doGlobalStuff() function window object will contain doGlobalStuff() method, but there is no doStuff() method in there.
However, this function will create method doStuff() in window object:

```
function doGlobalStuff()
{
    window.doStuff = function(){
    // do lots of fun stuff
    }
}
```

Search for variable and function scope for more info, like this:
[What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between these two as long as the first is declared in a global scope.

Answer (score 0):

The first will work out of browser contexts, where `window` isn't available. It also has a name (regardless of what variable or method key it's assigned to), which is useful for, among other things, stack traces and recursion.

The second won't work in, say, node.js (although `global` would). It doesn't have a name of it's own, which makes recursion difficult, as in the following example:

```
window.doStuff = function( i ){
    if( --i ){
        return window.doStuff();
    }

    return i;
}
```

If window.doStuff gets assigned something else, as follows…

```
window.doStuff = 'erg';
```

…then the above function breaks, because it's anonymous and can't reference itself — it's essentially lost.

Of course, there's nothing stopping you from doing both:

```
window.doStuff = function doStuff(){
    //do lots of fun stuff
}
```